# Very slow download speed using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

The bit of code below is used to download data "packages" consisting of zipped JSON, or zipped jpg images.  The issue is the image zip file download.  The file in question is 5 MB, and takes about 10 min to download on a 64GB iphone 7, and about 5 min on the simulator running on a fairly generously provisioned iMac.

The received data is stored, but not processed until all files are downloaded, so there should be nothing going on elsewhere until downloading is complete.

This seems quite excessive as I can download the file using a web browser in a negligible period of time.  I have looked at various questions and answers and haven't found anything useful.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
-(NSInteger)getPackageData:(NSString *)url type:(NSInteger)isZip fileName:(NSString *)fileName
item:(NSString *)item

{

__block NSInteger errorCode=0;
isReady=0;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration    defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

if(isZip==0){
    manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
}else{
    manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
}


AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
[policy setValidatesDomainName:YES];
manager.securityPolicy = policy;

/****************

 for self signed certs
 manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
 manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;

 ***************/

NSURL *mURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:mURL];

[request setCachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:100];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request
           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                               id json,
                               NSError *error) {

               if (error) {

                   if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

                       //error condition 1

                       NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *) response statusCode];

                       if(statusCode==403){   // unauthorized
                           errorCode=-1;
                       }
                   }

               }

               else if(isZip==1){
                   // process Zipped json Files for data update

                   NSString *filePath = [jsonPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

                   [json writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dataReady" object:item];
                   errorCode=0;

               }else if(isZip==2){  //zipped photos file

                   NSString *filePath = [photoPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                   CS_LOG(@"Saving URL %@ to photo file %@",url,filePath);
                   [json writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
                   CLS_LOG(@"Saved");

                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dataReady" object:@"PHOTOSREADY"];
                   errorCode=0;
               }


           } ];

[dataTask resume];
return errorCode;

}
```

Comment: May not help you, but first thing I would do is replace your function with the "basic" AFNetworking download task code. See how the speed is with that. If it's quicker, start adding back in the other features that you have above, until you hit something that is slowing things down.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you-I shall rewrite this piece and see what happens.  Offhand, it's hard for me to think of a more minimal implementation though.

Comment: Hmmm... you might have a logical reason for this, but... In general, NSURLSessionDataTask is used for small bits of data which are then manipulated in memory, whereas NSURLSessionDownloadTask is used for downloading large amounts of data (such as a zip file) and storing it on disk. Perhaps you should use DownloadTask for your big zips, and DataTask for your JSON data.

Comment: @DonMag I don't have a logical reason for this! ;-). I can make that change-thanks!

Comment: @DonMag That helped a great deal.  If you will make that into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `NSURLSessionDataTask` is used for small bits of data which are then manipulated in memory, whereas `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is used for downloading large amounts of data (such as a zip file) and storing it on disk.

Perhaps you should use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` for your big zips, and `NSURLSessionDataTask` for your JSON data.